# Code working in functions.php but not pluign for gavity forms

Tags: php, plugin-gravity-forms

I am trying to create a plugin for Gavity Forms I have a bit of code that is working in functions .php and have it working fine but what i need to understand is the plugin avity forms  ie how to integerate thcode into a plugin do the add filters just work.

```
add_filter("gform_confirmation", "custom_confirmation", 10, 4);
function custom_confirmation($confirmation, $form, $lead, $ajax){
 $gfe = $lead['id'];
```

I am using the code example here to produce a plugin from gravity 
https://github.com/rocketgenius/simpleaddon

simpleaddon.php source

```
<?php
    /*
    Plugin Name: Gravity Forms Simple Add-On
    Plugin URI: http://www.gravityforms.com
    Description: A simple add-on to demonstrate the use of the Add-On Framework
    Version: 1.1
    Author: Rocketgenius
    Author URI: http://www.rocketgenius.com
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Copyright 2012-2013 Rocketgenius Inc.
    This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
    the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
    (at your option) any later version.
    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the
    GNU General Public License for more details.
    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
    along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
    Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA 02111-1307 USA
    */
    //------------------------------------------
    if (class_exists("GFForms")) {
        GFForms::include_addon_framework();
        class GFSimpleAddOn extends GFAddOn {
            protected $_version = "1.1";
            protected $_min_gravityforms_version = "1.7.9999";
            protected $_slug = "simpleaddon";
            protected $_path = "asimpleaddon/asimpleaddon.php";
            protected $_full_path = __FILE__;
            protected $_title = "Gravity Forms Simple Add-On";
            protected $_short_title = "Simple Add-On";
            public function init(){
                parent::init();
                add_filter("gform_submit_button", array($this, "form_submit_button"), 10, 2);
            }
            // Add the text in the plugin settings to the bottom of the form if enabled for this form
            function form_submit_button($button, $form){
                $settings = $this->get_form_settings($form);
                if(isset($settings["enabled"]) && true == $settings["enabled"]){
                    $text = $this->get_plugin_setting("mytextbox");
                    $button = "<div>{$text}</div>" . $button;
                }
                return $button;
            }
            public function plugin_page() {
                ?>
                This page appears in the Forms menu
            <?php
            }
            public function form_settings_fields($form) {
                return array(
                    array(
                        "title"  => "Simple Form Settings",
                        "fields" => array(
                            array(
                                "label"   => "My checkbox",
                                "type"    => "checkbox",
                                "name"    => "enabled",
                                "tooltip" => "This is the tooltip",
                                "choices" => array(
                                    array(
                                        "label" => "Enabled",
                                        "name"  => "enabled"
                                    )
                                )
                            ),
                            array(
                                "label"   => "My checkboxes",
                                "type"    => "checkbox",
                                "name"    => "checkboxgroup",
                                "tooltip" => "This is the tooltip",
                                "choices" => array(
                                    array(
                                        "label" => "First Choice",
                                        "name"  => "first"
                                    ),
                                    array(
                                        "label" => "Second Choice",
                                        "name"  => "second"
                                    ),
                                    array(
                                        "label" => "Third Choice",
                                        "name"  => "third"
                                    )
                                )
                            ),
                            array(
                                "label"   => "My Radio Buttons",
                                "type"    => "radio",
                                "name"    => "myradiogroup",
                                "tooltip" => "This is the tooltip",
                                "choices" => array(
                                    array(
                                        "label" => "First Choice"
                                    ),
                                    array(
                                        "label" => "Second Choice"
                                    ),
                                    array(
                                        "label" => "Third Choice"
                                    )
                                )
                            ),
                            array(
                                "label"   => "My Horizontal Radio Buttons",
                                "type"    => "radio",
                                "horizontal" => true,
                                "name"    => "myradiogrouph",
                                "tooltip" => "This is the tooltip",
                                "choices" => array(
                                    array(
                                        "label" => "First Choice"
                                    ),
                                    array(
                                        "label" => "Second Choice"
                                    ),
                                    array(
                                        "label" => "Third Choice"
                                    )
                                )
                            ),
                            array(
                                "label"   => "My Dropdown",
                                "type"    => "select",
                                "name"    => "mydropdown",
                                "tooltip" => "This is the tooltip",
                                "choices" => array(
                                    array(
                                        "label" => "First Choice",
                                        "value" => "first"
                                    ),
                                    array(
                                        "label" => "Second Choice",
                                        "value" => "second"
                                    ),
                                    array(
                                        "label" => "Third Choice",
                                        "value" => "third"
                                    )
                                )
                            ),
                            array(
                                "label"   => "My Text Box",
                                "type"    => "text",
                                "name"    => "mytext",
                                "tooltip" => "This is the tooltip",
                                "class"   => "medium",
                                "feedback_callback" => array($this, "is_valid_setting")
                            ),
                            array(
                                "label"   => "My Text Area",
                                "type"    => "textarea",
                                "name"    => "mytextarea",
                                "tooltip" => "This is the tooltip",
                                "class"   => "medium merge-tag-support mt-position-right"
                            ),
                            array(
                                "label"   => "My Hidden Field",
                                "type"    => "hidden",
                                "name"    => "myhidden"
                            ),
                            array(
                                "label"   => "My Custom Field",
                                "type"    => "my_custom_field_type",
                                "name"    => "my_custom_field"
                            )
                        )
                    )
                );
            }
            public function settings_my_custom_field_type(){
                ?>
                <div>
                    My custom field contains a few settings:
                </div>
                <?php
                    $this->settings_text(
                        array(
                            "label" => "A textbox sub-field",
                            "name" => "subtext",
                            "default_value" => "change me"
                        )
                    );
                    $this->settings_checkbox(
                        array(
                            "label" => "A checkbox sub-field",
                            "choices" => array(
                                array(
                                    "label" => "Activate",
                                    "name" => "subcheck",
                                    "default_value" => true
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    );
            }
            public function plugin_settings_fields() {
                return array(
                    array(
                        "title"  => "Simple Add-On Settings",
                        "fields" => array(
                            array(
                                "name"    => "mytextbox",
                                "tooltip" => "This is the tooltip",
                                "label"   => "This is the label",
                                "type"    => "text",
                                "class"   => "small",
                                "feedback_callback" => array($this, "is_valid_setting")
                            )
                        )
                    )
                );
            }
            public function is_valid_setting($value){
                return strlen($value) < 10;
            }
            public function scripts() {
                $scripts = array(
                    array("handle"  => "my_script_js",
                          "src"     => $this->get_base_url() . "/js/my_script.js",
                          "version" => $this->_version,
                          "deps"    => array("jquery"),
                          "strings" => array(
                              'first'  => __("First Choice", "simpleaddon"),
                              'second' => __("Second Choice", "simpleaddon"),
                              'third'  => __("Third Choice", "simpleaddon")
                          ),
                          "enqueue" => array(
                              array(
                                  "admin_page" => array("form_settings"),
                                  "tab"        => "simpleaddon"
                              )
                          )
                    ),
                );
                return array_merge(parent::scripts(), $scripts);
            }
            public function styles() {
                $styles = array(
                    array("handle"  => "my_styles_css",
                          "src"     => $this->get_base_url() . "/css/my_styles.css",
                          "version" => $this->_version,
                          "enqueue" => array(
                              array("field_types" => array("poll"))
                          )
                    )
                );
                return array_merge(parent::styles(), $styles);
            }
        }
        new GFSimpleAddOn();
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question: Summarize your exact problem in the title, fix all spelling errors, and reduce your code to the necessary minimum.

Comment: i re adjusted my quesiton but the content is fine ! spelling is a matter of course and when i dont unclude code im asked for more so ur arguments are incorrect actually

Comment: I'm not sure what that add-on code has to do with your filter code, but if you're just trying to put that filter in a plugin, copy and paste it into a php file and give it a [plugin header](https://codex.wordpress.org/File_Header). done.

Answer (score 0):

Put the add_filter() call in the init function:

```
public function init(){
    parent::init();
    add_filter("gform_submit_button", array($this, "form_submit_button"), 10, 2);
    add_filter("gform_confirmation", array( $this, 'custom_confirmation' ), 10, 4 );
}
```

And then add your custom_confirmation() function as a method to the class:

```
class GFSimpleAddOn extends GFAddOn {

    /* all the other properties and methods */

    public function custom_confirmation($confirmation, $form, $lead, $ajax){
        $gfe = $lead['id'];
        // rest of your code
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks david ill give that a try by the way you see that code it appears to work for any version befoer 1.8.0 any ideas if you into gravity forms also anyway to protect my plguin code